# MySQL - how to improve complex query that uses multiple LEFT JOINs

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I have the following fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/21cee/2

Here's the schema for the DB tables:

**averages**:

```
id
subject_id
student_id
value
semester_id
```

**classes_students**:

```
id
class_academic_year_id
student_id
```

**classes_academic_years**:

```
id
class_id
name
academic_year_id
grade
```

**classes_subjects**:

```
id
class_academic_year_id
subject_id
```

**class_masters**:

```
id
class_academic_year_id
professor_id
```

**professors**:

```
id
school_id
first_name
last_name
```

**professors_subjects**:

```
id
professor_id
subject_id
```

**professors_classes_subjects**:

```
id
professor_id
class_academic_year_id
subject_id
```

**subjects**:

```
id
name
school_id
default
```

**semesters**:

```
id
name
academic_year_id
start_date
end_date
```

**students**:

```
id
last_name
first_name
```

I've got the following queries:

```
SELECT `averages`.* 
FROM `averages` 
INNER JOIN `classes_students` ON classes_students.student_id = averages.student_id 
INNER JOIN `classes_academic_years` ON classes_academic_years.id = classes_students.class_academic_year_id 
INNER JOIN `classes_subjects` ON classes_subjects.class_academic_year_id = classes_academic_years.id 
INNER JOIN `subjects` ON subjects.id = classes_subjects.subject_id 
INNER JOIN `professors_classes_subjects` ON professors_classes_subjects.class_academic_year_id = classes_subjects.class_academic_year_id 
INNER JOIN `professors_subjects` ON professors_subjects.professor_id = professors_classes_subjects.professor_id 
INNER JOIN `professors` ON professors.id = professors_subjects.professor_id 
INNER JOIN `semesters` ON semesters.academic_year_id = classes_academic_years.academic_year_id 
INNER JOIN `students` ON students.id = classes_students.student_id 

WHERE (classes_academic_years.academic_year_id = 3) 
AND (subjects.id = 72) 
AND (professors.id = 198) 
AND (professors_classes_subjects.subject_id = subjects.id) 
AND (professors_subjects.subject_id = subjects.id) 
AND (averages.subject_id = subjects.id) 
AND (averages.semester_id = semesters.id) 

ORDER BY `averages`.`student_id` asc, `averages`.`semester_id` asc;
```

and

```
SELECT `averages`.* 
FROM `averages` 
INNER JOIN `classes_students` ON classes_students.student_id = averages.student_id 
INNER JOIN `classes_academic_years` ON classes_academic_years.id = classes_students.class_academic_year_id 
INNER JOIN `classes_subjects` ON classes_subjects.class_academic_year_id = classes_academic_years.id 
INNER JOIN `subjects` ON subjects.id = classes_subjects.subject_id 
INNER JOIN `class_masters` ON class_masters.class_academic_year_id = classes_academic_years.id
INNER JOIN `semesters` ON semesters.academic_year_id = classes_academic_years.academic_year_id 
INNER JOIN `students` ON students.id = classes_students.student_id 

WHERE (classes_academic_years.academic_year_id = 3) 
AND (subjects.id = 72) 
AND (class_masters.professor_id = 198)
AND (averages.subject_id = subjects.id) 
AND (averages.semester_id = semesters.id) 

ORDER BY `averages`.`student_id` asc, `averages`.`semester_id` asc;
```

The first query fetches the averages for a certain subject (`subject_id = 72`) of a certain professor (`professor_id = 198`), for all the classes the professor is assigned to.

Since `professor_id = 198` is NOT assigned to `subject_id = 72` for any class, the result is going to be empty.

The second query fetches the averages for a certain subject (`subject_id = 72`) of a certain professor (`professor_id = 198`), checking only those classes that the given professor is a class_master of, regardless of which professor is assigned to that subject to that class.

Both queries work fine. I need to combine these two queries, and here's my attempt:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `averages`.* FROM `averages` 
INNER JOIN `classes_students` ON classes_students.student_id = averages.student_id 
INNER JOIN `classes_academic_years` ON classes_academic_years.id = classes_students.class_academic_year_id 
INNER JOIN `classes_subjects` ON classes_subjects.class_academic_year_id = classes_academic_years.id 
INNER JOIN `subjects` ON subjects.id = classes_subjects.subject_id 
LEFT JOIN `professors_classes_subjects` ON professors_classes_subjects.class_academic_year_id = classes_subjects.class_academic_year_id 
LEFT JOIN `professors_subjects` ON professors_subjects.professor_id = professors_classes_subjects.professor_id 
LEFT JOIN `professors` ON professors.id = professors_subjects.professor_id 
LEFT JOIN `class_masters` ON class_masters.class_academic_year_id = classes_academic_years.id 
INNER JOIN `semesters` ON semesters.academic_year_id = classes_academic_years.academic_year_id 
INNER JOIN `students` ON students.id = classes_students.student_id 
WHERE (classes_academic_years.academic_year_id = 3) 
AND (subjects.id = 72) 
AND ((professors.id = 198 
AND professors_classes_subjects.subject_id = subjects.id 
AND professors_subjects.subject_id = subjects.id) 
OR (class_masters.id is not null AND class_masters.professor_id = 198)) 
AND (averages.subject_id = subjects.id) 
AND (averages.semester_id = semesters.id) 
ORDER BY `averages`.`student_id` asc, `averages`.`semester_id` asc;
```

While it indeed works fine, it is also VERY slow (e.g. it takes around 5 seconds for it to run on my local machine).

Is there a way to improve the third query?

LE: here's the EXPLAIN:

```
+----+-------------+-----------------------------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+---------+-----------------------------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type |            table            |  type  |                            possible_keys                            |                key                | key_len |                      ref                      | rows |                       Extra                        |
+----+-------------+-----------------------------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+---------+-----------------------------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | subjects                    | const  | PRIMARY                                                             | PRIMARY                           | 8       | const                                         |    1 | Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort       |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | averages                    | ref    | subject_id_student_id_semester_id                                   | subject_id_student_id_semester_id | 8       | const                                         | 1087 | (NULL)                                             |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | students                    | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                             | PRIMARY                           | 8       | averages.student_id                           |    1 | Using index                                        |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | classes_students            | ref    | student_id,class_academic_year_id_student_id                        | student_id                        | 8       | averages.student_id                           |    2 | (NULL)                                             |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | semesters                   | eq_ref | PRIMARY,academic_year_id                                            | PRIMARY                           | 4       | averages.semester_id                          |    1 | (NULL)                                             |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | classes_subjects            | ref    | subject_id,class_academic_year_id,class_academic_year_id_subject_id | class_academic_year_id_subject_id | 16      | classes_students.class_academic_year_id,const |    1 | Using index                                        |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | classes_academic_years      | eq_ref | PRIMARY,id_class_id_academic_year_id,id_academic_year_id            | PRIMARY                           | 8       | classes_students.class_academic_year_id       |    1 | Using where                                        |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | professors_classes_subjects | ALL    | (NULL)                                                              | (NULL)                            | (NULL)  | (NULL)                                        |  822 | Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop) |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | professors_subjects         | ALL    | (NULL)                                                              | (NULL)                            | (NULL)  | (NULL)                                        |  304 | Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop) |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | professors                  | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                             | PRIMARY                           | 8       | professors_subjects.professor_id              |    1 | Using index                                        |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | class_masters               | ALL    | (NULL)                                                              | (NULL)                            | (NULL)  | (NULL)                                        |   97 | Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop) |
+----+-------------+-----------------------------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+---------+-----------------------------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------------+
```

LE: I've managed to solve it, by refining the ON condition for two of the LEFT JOINs, as such:

```
SELECT averages.* FROM `averages` 
INNER JOIN `classes_students` ON classes_students.student_id = averages.student_id 
INNER JOIN `classes_academic_years` ON classes_academic_years.id = classes_students.class_academic_year_id 
INNER JOIN `classes_subjects` ON classes_subjects.class_academic_year_id = classes_academic_years.id 
INNER JOIN `subjects` ON subjects.id = classes_subjects.subject_id 
LEFT JOIN `professors_classes_subjects` ON professors_classes_subjects.class_academic_year_id = classes_subjects.class_academic_year_id AND professors_classes_subjects.subject_id = subjects.id
LEFT JOIN `professors_subjects` ON professors_subjects.professor_id = professors_classes_subjects.professor_id AND professors_subjects.subject_id = subjects.id
LEFT JOIN `professors` ON professors.id = professors_subjects.professor_id 
LEFT JOIN `class_masters` ON class_masters.class_academic_year_id = classes_academic_years.id 
INNER JOIN `semesters` ON semesters.academic_year_id = classes_academic_years.academic_year_id 
INNER JOIN `students` ON students.id = classes_students.student_id 
WHERE (classes_academic_years.academic_year_id = 3) 
AND (subjects.id = 72) 
AND ((professors.id = 198) 
OR (class_masters.id is not null AND class_masters.professor_id = 198)) 
AND (averages.subject_id = subjects.id) 
AND (averages.semester_id = semesters.id) 
ORDER BY `averages`.`student_id` asc, `averages`.`semester_id` asc;
```

I added two conditions (marked as bold), thus eliminating the need of using the DISTINCT operator:

`LEFT JOIN professors_classes_subjects ON professors_classes_subjects.class_academic_year_id = classes_subjects.class_academic_year_id`**AND professors_classes_subjects.subject_id = subjects.id**
`LEFT JOIN professors_subjects ON professors_subjects.professor_id = professors_classes_subjects.professor_id`**AND professors_subjects.subject_id = subjects.id**

Comment: BTW, this bit looks odd... "AND (professors_classes_subjects.subject_id = subjects.id) 
AND (professors_subjects.subject_id = subjects.id) 
AND (averages.subject_id = subjects.id) 
AND (averages.semester_id = semesters.id)

Comment: Previously there's "AND (subjects.id = 72)". 

I could have written "AND (professors_classes_subjects = 72) AND (professors_subjects.subjects.id = 72) AND (averages.subject_id = 72)" but it doesn't make any difference regarding performance.

Comment: But then why use "LEFT JOIN"? These WHERE conditions render those as INNER JOIN! Apart from that, your query looks quite good, so to help further we'd really need to see the EXPLAIN (in addition to the DDLs already provided)

Comment: Also "DISTINCT a.*" seems nonsensical to me.

Comment: Have you tried running the query?

AND ((professors.id = 198 
AND professors_classes_subjects.subject_id = subjects.id 
AND professors_subjects.subject_id = subjects.id) OR (class_masters.id is not null AND class_masters.professor_id = 198))

I'm using LEFT JOINs so that it fetches the combined results from both queries previously provided. Is there any solution to avoid using LEFT JOIN?

Also, what's wrong with the WHERE conditions? Please notice that there's AND ( (condition) OR (condition) ) in order to meet both LEFT JOIN cases (either professor is assigned to subject, or is class master)

Comment: @Daniel There does not seem to be enough data in the SQL Fiddle. There is only one row in the `averages` table. Why is `student_id` included in the `averages` table? What does value=FB mean?

Comment: @JosephB, I couldn't include more data (there's the 8000 characters limit from sqlfiddle). I've included the minimum relevant row (there's the case I'm locally trying to solve, and it's got only one row). The student_id is included in the averages table, because each student has an average for each subject it takes during a semester (therefore I've got student_id, subject_id, value, and semester_id). FB is a grade for elementary classes in Romania (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Education_in_Romania#Grading_conventions)

Comment: The EXPLAIN is the important bit

Comment: @Strawberry You can see the EXPLAIN PLAN on the SQL Fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/21cee/2

Comment: No.The EXPLAIN has to come from your actual data set. Paste the result of EXPLAIN SELECT DISTINCT averages.* ...

Comment: OK - I get the DISTINCT bit, but now the LEFT JOINing tables from which you select no columns make no sense either :-(

Comment: Please consider re-posting your solution as an *answer*. The thing is, that way you will be able to accept your own answer eventually (in 2 days since posting), by which means your question will have a proper indication that it's been answered. (No need to put "SOLVED:" into the title.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to solve it, by refining the ON condition for two of the LEFT JOINs, as such:

```
SELECT averages.* FROM `averages` 
INNER JOIN `classes_students` ON classes_students.student_id = averages.student_id 
INNER JOIN `classes_academic_years` ON classes_academic_years.id = classes_students.class_academic_year_id 
INNER JOIN `classes_subjects` ON classes_subjects.class_academic_year_id = classes_academic_years.id 
INNER JOIN `subjects` ON subjects.id = classes_subjects.subject_id 
LEFT JOIN `professors_classes_subjects` ON professors_classes_subjects.class_academic_year_id = classes_subjects.class_academic_year_id AND professors_classes_subjects.subject_id = subjects.id
LEFT JOIN `professors_subjects` ON professors_subjects.professor_id = professors_classes_subjects.professor_id AND professors_subjects.subject_id = subjects.id
LEFT JOIN `professors` ON professors.id = professors_subjects.professor_id 
LEFT JOIN `class_masters` ON class_masters.class_academic_year_id = classes_academic_years.id 
INNER JOIN `semesters` ON semesters.academic_year_id = classes_academic_years.academic_year_id 
INNER JOIN `students` ON students.id = classes_students.student_id 
WHERE (classes_academic_years.academic_year_id = 3) 
AND (subjects.id = 72) 
AND ((professors.id = 198) 
OR (class_masters.id is not null AND class_masters.professor_id = 198)) 
AND (averages.subject_id = subjects.id) 
AND (averages.semester_id = semesters.id) 
ORDER BY `averages`.`student_id` asc, `averages`.`semester_id` asc;
```

I added two conditions (marked as bold), thus eliminating the need of using the DISTINCT operator:

```
LEFT JOIN professors_classes_subjects
  ON professors_classes_subjects.class_academic_year_id = classes_subjects.class_academic_year_id
 AND professors_classes_subjects.subject_id = subjects.id
LEFT JOIN professors_subjects
  ON professors_subjects.professor_id = professors_classes_subjects.professor_id
 AND professors_subjects.subject_id = subjects.id
```

Comment: Using short table aliases might improve readability of your queries. (Cf. `LEFT JOIN professors_classes_subjects AS pcs ON pcs.class_academic_year_id = cs.class_academic_year_id AND pcs.subject_id = sbj.id`.)

Comment: @AndriyM I tried to hint at something like that in one of my earlier responsnes. Hint not taken, so good to spell it out!